# Programming Pattern: Representation of pick up objects

Tags: architecture, gameobject

I'm pondering about the best way to represent objects that can be picked up in my 2D engine.

I have an **Actor** class which is the base for all objects that can be spawned into the game. This class offers a location and some other information needed by all actors.

Now, let's take an Apple for example. It's derived from **Actor** and carries with it all the information needed to be in the game-world. But when I pick this item up and put it inside an inventory, I don't need all that **Actor** stuff. So I was pondering. Does it make sense to maybe have an **AppleActor** class instead that derives from **Actor**, and inside it have an **Apple** class derived from something like **InventoryItem**?

When I pick up an **Actor**, I would take the **InventoryItem** out of it, store it in my inventory and destroy the **Actor**. Then, when I drop the **InventoryItem**, I would first create the corresponding **Actor** for it, put the **InventoryItem** inside it and spawn that **Actor** in the world.

Does this make sense at all? Any feedback or advice from more experienced people here is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the underlying data model for my inventory separate from the visual representation ([MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) basically) for exactly the reasons you bring up. I'd have an AppleActor while the object is actually spawned out in the world, but once I pick it up it's just an ID (probably a key in a dictionary that associates ID with amount) in the InventoryModel.

Comment: And how would you handle **Actor** creation? Should the **InventoryItem** offer an **ActorFactory** method?

Comment: I'd probably do ActorFactory as a separate class that just takes in an item ID, rather than something owned by InventoryItem, but basically yes.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make `Apple` an `Actor`.
Make `Apple` an `Item` and allow `Actor`s to hold references to them via a backpack, which could just be a `List` or array of `Item`, or a hand which is a `Item` ref. Now your `Actor` can just walk around picking up and dropping `Item`s, as in the real world.

Related: You'll find dynamic languages tend to have a top-level `object` type. You'll notice these usually don't have much in them, because when that `object` can represent just about anything in its role as a base class, it's very difficult to get specific about it without forcing derived objects to carry around unnecessary methods and members. The same is true in your case; while it may seem attractive to have some sort of generic, top-level `GameObject` class (in your case, `Actor`), it's not always the right way to go about things. You've said you need e.g. `position`... so, OK then.

I would keep `Actor` for actual walking, talking things and use a different name for your top level... if you decide to have a top level at all.

The way to decide that is to ask, "In what ways are these objects processed similarly?" If they are never processed or held in the same ways, then don't bother having them derive from the same base class. If they are processed in some similar yet abstract way, then do give them a base.